# why does it write over the same line?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why every time I create a new instance it writes over the same line?
When I open the file it has just the last object attributes.
I tried with f.seek(0,2) and it don't work.

```
class persoana(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.nume = input("Nume:")
        self.idd = int(input("Id:"))
        self.tel = input("Telefon:")
        self.adress = input("Adresa:")
        self.write()

    def write(self):
        f = open('persoane.txt','w')
        f.write("\n" + "#" + self.nume + "," + str(self.idd) + "," + self.tel + "," + self.adress)
        f.close()
```

Comment: Because you open the file in (over)`w`rite mode every time.

Comment: See documentation for [**`open`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open), particularly the `mode` parameter.

Comment: ok, thanks for answering that fast :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to open the file in append mode.

```
class persoana(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.nume = input("Nume:")
        self.idd = int(input("Id:"))
        self.tel = input("Telefon:")
        self.adress = input("Adresa:")
        self.write()

    def write(self):
        f = open('persoane.txt','a')
        f.write("\n" + "#" + self.nume + "," + str(self.idd) + "," + self.tel + "," + self.adress)
        f.close()
```

Additionally, its preferred to use the `with open(filename) as f` format as follows:

```
def write(self):
    with open('persoane.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write("\n" + "#" + self.nume + "," + str(self.idd) + "," + self.tel + "," + self.adress)
```

This will manage the closing of your file in the case of an exception or error.